# Se cierra mi aplicación de Android Studio cuando presiono el botón

Tags: java, android

Soy nuevo en *Android Studio*, esta aplicación en realidad es una práctica, pero ya me ha pasado con varias aplicaciones que se cierran cuando presiono el botón y no sé dónde está el error.

Código:

```
package com.example.edittextstring;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etn, etp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre);
        etp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_pasword);
    }

    //metodo para boton
    public void registrar(View view){

        String nombre = etn.getText().toString();
        String contra = etp.getText().toString();

        if(nombre.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debes ingresar un nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(contra.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debes ingresar una contrasena", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(nombre.length() != 0 && contra.length()!= 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registro en Proceso...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Algunas aplicaciones funcionan bien hasta que alguna opción falla y se cierran, el programa no me tira ningún error al hacer el *Debug*, así que no sé por dónde empezar a corregirlo.

El botón en el código no esta declarado como objeto pero **es el que activa el método** `registrar`.

Comment: y que muestra el Logcat??

Comment: Si alguna respuesta resolvió el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo tu mètodo registrar y defines que este recibira como parametro una vista:

```
public void registrar(View view){
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Debes llamar este mètodo desde el botòn definido en el layout mediante `android:onClick` de esta forma:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="llama metodo registrar!"
    android:onClick="registrar" />
```

Dentro del mètodo `registrar()` usa `getApplicationContext()` como contexto en lugar de `this` :

```
//metodo para boton
public void registrar(View view){

    String nombre = etn.getText().toString();
    String contra = etp.getText().toString();

    if(nombre.length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes ingresar un nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(contra.length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes ingresar una contrasena", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(nombre.length() != 0 && contra.length()!= 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro en Proceso...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```